# Convert from stored procedure to SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want a SQL query for the third procedure

Convert this stored procedure to a SQL query :

```
CREATE PROC [WaterlilyT].[uisp_Rep_HRClearance_RND]
(
        @pnCompCode DECIMAL(18,0)=0,
        @pnClearanceNo VARCHAR(5000)='',
        @AsonDate varchar(20)='1900-01-01'
)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempHRCLNos') IS NOT NULL 
       DROP TABLE #TempHRCLNos

    SELECT CAST(val AS Decimal(18,0)) clslno 
    INTO #TempHRCLNos  
    FROM dbo.split(@pnClearanceNo,',')   

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_TempHRCLslno ON #TempHRCLNos(clslno) 

    DECLARE @pnVisaReq decimal
    SET @pnVisaReq = 0

    DECLARE @ldAsonDate Date
    SET @ldAsonDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, AsonDate, 103)

        --if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempHRCLVisaReq') is not null drop table #TempHRCLVisaReq
        if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempHRCLJoining') is not null drop table #TempHRCLJoining

        SELECT c.serialno,d.posiref posname,d.gender,count(a.serialno) visareq,count(b.serialno) visarefused,count(e.serialno) visarec
        Into #TempHRCLVisaReq
        FROM [WaterlilyT].[vtwfhclearance] c 
        Join [WaterlilyT].[vtwfhvisaprocreq] a on a.clearno = c.serialno
        join waterlilyt.vtwfhofferletter ofr on ofr.serialno = a.offrefno 
        join waterlilyt.vtwfhresbnk res on res.serialno = ofr.candcode 
        join [WaterlilyT].[vtwfdpclearance] d on d.serialno = c.serialno and d.gender = res.gender 
        left join [WaterlilyT].[vtwfhvisaprociss] b on b.visareq = a.serialno and b.visastat = 20
        left join [WaterlilyT].[vtwfhvisaprociss] e on e.visareq = a.serialno and e.visastat = 10
        where  isnull(a.appstat,0) = 50 
        and  (@pnCompCode =0 or (@pnCompCode !=0  and @pnCompCode = a.bcd))
        and (@pnClearanceNo ='' or (@pnClearanceNo != '' and exists (select 1 from  #TempHRCLNos where clslno=a.clearno)))
        and (@ldAsonDate = '1900-01-01' or (@ldAsonDate <> '1900-01-01' and c.clearpdt < Dateadd(day,1,@ldAsonDate)  ) )
        Group by c.serialno,d.posiref,d.gender


        SELECT c.serialno,e.codeval desg,f.gender gendercode ,count(jp.serialno) joincnt
        Into #TempHRCLJoining
        FROM WaterlilyT.vtwfhjoinprocess jp 
        join waterlilyt.vtwfhresbnk f on f.serialno = jp.candcd 
        Join [WaterlilyT].[vtwfhvisaprocreq] vreq on jp.offerno = isnull(vreq.offrefno,0) 
        Join [WaterlilyT].[vtwfhclearance] c on vreq.clearno = c.serialno 
        --Join UlexM.vmunmglobal e on isnull(e.serialno,'') = vreq.posname and  gtype = 'DESIG' and isactive = 1 and islstlvl = 1 
        --Join [WaterlilyT].[vtwfdpclearance] d on d.serialno = c.serialno and d.posiref = isnull(e.strvalue,0) and d.gender = f.gender
        join Ulexm.vmundgeneral e on e.mastcd = 'CLRPOS' and e.codeval = vreq.posname
        Join [WaterlilyT].[vtwfdpclearance] d on d.serialno = c.serialno and d.posiref = isnull(e.codeval,0) and d.gender = f.gender
        where  isnull(jp.appstat,0) =50 and jp.jointyp <> 10 and isnull(vreq.appstat,0) = 50  
        and  (@pnCompCode =0 or (@pnCompCode !=0  and @pnCompCode = jp.bcd))
        and (@pnClearanceNo ='' or (@pnClearanceNo != '' and exists (select 1 from  #TempHRCLNos where clslno=vreq.clearno)))
        and (@ldAsonDate = '1900-01-01' or (@ldAsonDate <> '1900-01-01' and c.clearpdt < Dateadd(day,1,@ldAsonDate)) )
        Group by c.serialno,e.codeval,f.gender

        /*SELECT hc.serialno,SlNo,ClearanceNo,Convert(Varchar(10),Clearancedate,103) Clearancedate,Positioncode,PositionName,
        hc.Gender,isnull(TotalNumber,0) TotalNumber,validityDate,
        Case When validityDate >= Case when @ldAsonDate ='1900-01-01' then getdate()  else @ldAsonDate end  then  
        DATEDIFF(DAY,Case when @ldAsonDate ='1900-01-01' then getdate() else @ldAsonDate end,validityDate) Else  0 End DaysToGo,
        --isnull(vreq.visareq,0) [VisaRequested],
        isnull(req.visareq,0) [VisaRequested],
        isnull(req.visarefused,0)  RefusedByROP ,isnull(req.visareq,0)-isnull(req.visarefused,0)  [VisaRecd],isnull(jp.joincnt,0) Joined,
        (isnull(req.visareq,0)-isnull(req.visarefused,0)) - isnull(jp.joincnt,0) EmpYetToJoin,VisaExpired,
        isnull(TotalNumber,0) - (isnull(req.visareq,0) + isnull(req.visarefused,0) + VisaExpired ) Pending 
        FROM WaterlilyT.vinforClearance hc
        --left Join #TempHRCLVisaReq vreq on hc.serialno =vreq.serialno and hc.desg = vreq.desg
        --Left Join #TempHRCLJoining jp on hc.serialno =jp.serialno and hc.desg =jp.desg
        Left Join #TempHRCLJoining jp on hc.serialno =jp.serialno and hc.PositionCode =jp.desg and jp.gendercode = hc.gendercode 
        Left Join #TempHRCLVisaReq req on req.serialno = hc.serialno and req.posname = hc.PositionCode and req.gender = hc.gendercode 
        where  (@pnCompCode =0 or (@pnCompCode !=0  and @pnCompCode = hc.bcd))
        and (@pnClearanceNo ='' or (@pnClearanceNo != '' and exists (select 1 from  #TempHRCLNos where clslno=hc.serialno)))
        and (@ldAsonDate = '1900-01-01' or (@ldAsonDate <> '1900-01-01' and Clearancedate < Dateadd(day,1,@ldAsonDate)  ) )*/

        SELECT hc.serialno,SlNo,ClearanceNo,Convert(Varchar(10),Clearancedate,103) Clearancedate,Positioncode,PositionName,
        hc.Gender,isnull(TotalNumber,0) TotalNumber,validityDate,
        Case When validityDate >= Case when @ldAsonDate ='1900-01-01' then getdate()  else @ldAsonDate end  then  
        DATEDIFF(DAY,Case when @ldAsonDate ='1900-01-01' then getdate() else @ldAsonDate end,validityDate) Else  0 End DaysToGo,
        isnull(req.visareq,0) [VisaRequested],
        isnull(req.visarefused,0)  RefusedByROP ,isnull(req.visarec,0)  [VisaRecd],isnull(jp.joincnt,0) Joined,
        isnull(req.visarec,0) - isnull(jp.joincnt,0) EmpYetToJoin,VisaExpired,
        isnull(TotalNumber,0) - (isnull(req.visareq,0) + isnull(req.visarefused,0) + VisaExpired ) Pending 
        FROM WaterlilyT.vinforClearance hc
        --left Join #TempHRCLVisaReq vreq on hc.serialno =vreq.serialno and hc.desg = vreq.desg
        --Left Join #TempHRCLJoining jp on hc.serialno =jp.serialno and hc.desg =jp.desg
        Left Join #TempHRCLJoining jp on hc.serialno =jp.serialno and hc.PositionCode =jp.desg and jp.gendercode = hc.gendercode 
        Left Join #TempHRCLVisaReq req on req.serialno = hc.serialno and req.posname = hc.PositionCode and req.gender = hc.gendercode 
        where  (@pnCompCode =0 or (@pnCompCode !=0  and @pnCompCode = hc.bcd))
        and (@pnClearanceNo ='' or (@pnClearanceNo != '' and exists (select 1 from  #TempHRCLNos where clslno=hc.serialno)))
        and (@ldAsonDate = '1900-01-01' or (@ldAsonDate <> '1900-01-01' and Clearancedate < Dateadd(day,1,@ldAsonDate)  ) )

        END
```

Comment: Remove create procedure with begin and end problem solved :D

Comment: so what is the error you are gettin?

Comment: Just select the third query, copy it to a new query window. After that you will need to replace the parameters (@pn...) with either values or declare some variables with these names. After that you will still have to set their values of course. The same goes for any other variables that have been declared, but for those you can just copy the declarations.